# Quicksilver addons and plugins

Tags: keyboard, quicksilver

Quicksilver is no doubt THE App that's must have for any keyboard ninja using Mac. Please share your [power] tips on new addons, triggers and plugins that you use.

Comment: That's an excellent question. I don't understand why some people down voted it.

Comment: @reg There's a lot of app launcher out there (I know, Quicksilver is more than that, but still...) and we simply can't have one topic for everyone of them. Besides, Quicksilver is no longer actively developed, since its main developer is now working on Google's Quick Search Bar.

Answer (score 1):

If you're using Quicksilver just as a launcher I recommend checking out "Google Quick Search Box" (http://www.google.com/quicksearchbox/).

Answer (score -4):

[Holywar mode on]

Quick silver is NOT the app that's must have for any keyboard ninja using Mac since Spotlight works like a charm.

Quicksilver was good on 10.3 as there were no Spotlight :).

[Holywar mode off]

Comment: Try moving files in Spotlight. ;) You can do just about anything you want in QS.

Comment: That's somewhat true if you're only using Quicksilver as a launcher.  It's considerably more than that.  However, even just as a launcher, I've found quicksilver to be:
-faster
-smarter (pulling up apps + commonly used files, rather than just the best search match)
-More adaptable (If you regularly type "pho" and switch down from the first result of Photobooth to the third result of Photoshop, it'll figure that out and start putting Photoshop first for "pho").